# Publishing ASP .NET Core App through Windows Power Shell

Tags: asp.net, powershell, asp.net-core

How can I publish correctly ASP .NET Core App through Windows Power Shell?

```
Write-Host ==== START PUBLISHING APP ==== -ForegroundColor Red
$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
$options = "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile='FolderProfile'"
$apiproj = $BackEndPath + "\DCMT.WebApi.csproj"

# Publish the WebApi to Server...
$build = $msbuild + " $apiproj " + $options
Invoke-Expression $build
```

Executing that command is giving me an error

```
error MSB4040: No target element in the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Publish the WebApi to Server...
$pathToCompile = "C:\DCMT\DCMT-INTERNS-SOURCE\DCMT-BackEnd\DCMT.WebApi\DCMT.WebApi\DCMT.WebApi.csproj"
dotnet publish $pathToCompile /p:PublishDir="C:\DCMT\DCMT-INTERNS"
```

I have changed the command to look like this and it works! :D